# How to model and load data from related tables using Sqflite

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart, sqflite

I have two related tables with a foreign key declared in my schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Collection(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT,
    start_date INT
);

CREATE TABLE Item (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    collection_id INTEGER,
    name TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY (collection_id) REFERENCES Collection(id)
);
```

And I have the models of these tables in Dart:

```
class Collection {
  int id;
  String name;
  DateTime startDate;
  List<Item> items;

  Collection({
    this.id,
    this.name = '',
    this.startDate,
    this.items,
  });

  factory Collection.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Collection(
    id            : json["id"],
    name          : json["name"],
    startDate     : DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(json["start_date"]),
    items         : List<Item>.from(json["items"].map((x) => Item.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id"            : id,
    "name"          : name,
    "start_date"    : startDate.millisecondsSinceEpoch,
    "items"         : List<dynamic>.from(items.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };


class Item {
  int id;
  int collection_id;
  String name;

  Item({
    this.id,
    this.collection_id,
    this.name = '',
  });

  factory Item.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Item(
    id            : json["id"],
    collection_id : json["collection_id"],
    name          : json["name"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id"            : id,
    "collection_id" : collection_id,
    "name"          : name,
  };
```

I am using a DB Provider to fetch data from database, but I do not know how to get data of main table, and related ones:

```
final response = await db.query('Collection', where: 'status = ?', whereArgs: ['in progress']);
return response.isNotEmpty ? Collection.fromJson(response.first) : null;
```

so I get a null exception when try to create an instance of Collection with no data in the items field.

**Do you know how to fetch data from main table and related ones in one query?**

Of course, I can do a second query to load it, but the idea es do that in one query.

Answer (score 2):

here a solution with a `Left Join rawQuery` and then you can `groupBy` your map and create a new Map the same you want like your Model

```
Future<List<Collection>> getcoll() async {
    var dbClient = await db;

    // rawQuery with Left Join over 2 Tables
    String query = 'SELECT C.id AS collection_id, ' +
        ' C.name AS cname, ' +
        ' C.start_date as start_date, ' +
        ' Item.id as id, ' +
        ' Item.name as name ' +
        ' FROM Collection C' +
        ' LEFT JOIN Item ON Item.collection_id = C.id';
    List<Map> result = await dbClient.rawQuery(query);

    // new Map groupBy collection_id
    var newMap = groupBy(result, (obj) => obj['collection_id']);

    // create new Map    
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> newMap2 = new List();
    newMap.forEach((f, values) {

      // add new Map the same as your Model
      newMap2.add({
        "id": f,
        "name": values[0]["cname"],  // use first value in list it is always the same
        "start_date": values[0]["start_date"],
        "items": values // all values from the item Table +Collection Fields but they are nut used
      });

    });

    // toList function to your List Model
    List<Collection> r_Collection = newMap2.map((i) => Collection.fromJson(i)).toList();

    return r_Collection;

  }
```